# How to print the last element of a slice in a EMQX Kuiper Rules with Go template?

Tags: go

I am using EMQX Kuiper.
https://docs.emqx.io/en/kuiper/latest/rules/overview.html#sinks-actions

Where in my rule settings, I am using `dataTemplate` property to fetch my data. Where I have to use Go template. No way to write go script only template.

Using this template I able to print first item of my slice.

```
 "dataTemplate": "{{json (index . 0)}}"
```

But I need to print last item of my slice. Can't print this.
Tried to achieve that with the Go template language like this,

```
"dataTemplate": "{{$lenMyList := len .}} {{json (index . $lenMyList -1)}}"
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Why not just use a `template.FuncMap` that includes a `lastElement` or similar?

Comment: Here is an example showing a couple ways to go about using a function for this. https://play.golang.org/p/opm9NS4BYYi

Comment: Hi @sberry thanks for reply,  as I know there is no option to write any script only have to use template.

Comment: @SaifulIslam It is not possible to get the last element of a slice without custom functions.  According to the [EMQX Kuiper documentation](https://docs.emqx.io/en/kuiper/latest/rules/overview.html#sinks-actions), the [sprig add function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html) is available in the template.  Use it like this: `index . (add $lenMyList -1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CeriseLimón. It works perfectly.